# Apache error Hostname myfirstweb.intweb.net provided via SNI and hostname mysecondweb.intweb.net provided via HTTP are different

Tags: apache, nginx

I have a server with around 3 websites on the same server.

To make things easier for me, I'm generating the nginx configuration files as well as the apache configuration files with ansible so it's easier and less error prone. and, as you will see below, I'm using the same port for all of them, so pretty much the only things are different on those apache and nginx configuration files are the server name, the root location the website location and where the error logs are going to be placed.

The problem that I see now is that I can't see both websites at the same time, when I open the first website on my browser it opens fine, but when I want to open the second website I get this error:

***Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.***

When I see apache logs I see the following error:

***[Fri Nov 09 16:17:51.247904 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 18614] AH02032: Hostname myweb.intweb.net provided via SNI and hostname mysecondweb.intweb.net provided via HTTP are different***

where *mysecondweb.intweb.net* is the other website I'm trying to see.

This is my nginx configuration file for one of them, where you can see I'm handling the request to apache:

```
# Force HTTP requests to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myweb.intweb.net;
    return 301 https://myweb.intweb.net$request_uri;
}
  server {

      listen  443 ssl;
      root  /var/opt/httpd/ifdocs;

    server_name myweb.intweb.net ;

      # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_intweb_net.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_intweb_net.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

      access_log /var/log/nginx/iflogs/https/access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/iflogs/https/error.log;

    ###include rewrites/default.conf;


    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make nginx serve static files instead of Apache
    # NOTE this will cause issues with bandwidth accounting as files wont be logged
    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4433;
         }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on <serverIP>:8080
    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_name $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:4433;
         }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
  root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

This is my Apache configuration for the same site:

```
 <VirtualHost *:4433>

  SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_intweb_net.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/star_intweb_net.key
SSLCertificateCcompanyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/DigiCertCA.crt

ServerAdmin webmaster@company.com

DocumentRoot /var/opt/httpd/ifdocs

<Directory "/var/opt/httpd/ifdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

ServerName myweb.intweb.net

ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/iflogs/http/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/iflogs/http/access.log combined

#    RewriteEngine on

#    Include rewrites/default.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why front Apache by nginx?  Both can do the whole thing, so why?

Comment: If you want to proxy to a client on localhost, why use https to localhost? Terminate the https in nginx and use http to connect to apache. This will save you encrypting and decrypting to avoid _network_ eavesdroppers on a connection that doesn't touch the network.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol Thank you for your comment, are you saying I should do http://localhost instead of https://localhost?

Comment: Stackoverflow seems to have garbled your reply to me. But yes, I'm saying use `http://localhost/` instead of `https://localhost/`